# R dplyr - How do I unquote an input so that it’s evaluated, not quoted - specifically ggplot coord_cart()

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(41000:41050, origin = "1899-12-30"), 
  value = c(rnorm(25, 5), rnorm(26, 10))
  )
```

I first create my data above. Then I try and create a function that, among other things, changes the ggplot coordinate scale.

```
scatter_plot_cart <- function(data, x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(data$(!!x)) + 100, max(data$(!!x)) - 100))
}

scatter_plot_cart(df, date, value)
```

> Error: unexpected '(' in: " geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim =
>   c(min(data$(" > } Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

I'm guessing from the error that I am not unquoting `x` properly in my `coord_cartesian()` syntax. What is the proper syntax? I know I'm almost there because my code below works.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(df$date) + 100, max(df$date) - 100))
```

Comment: Why not just use data[,x]?

Comment: @iod Just tried it in the following form and it didn't work. And would I need to unqoute `data[, !!x]` it? Is this what you meant `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(data[, x]) + 100, max(data[, x] - 100))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pre-calculate the axis limits beforehand

```
scatter_plot_cart <- function(data, x, y) {
    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)
    xlim <- c(
        data %>% pull(!!x) %>% min() + 100,
        data %>% pull(!!x) %>% max() - 100)
    ggplot(data, aes(!!x, !!y)) +
        geom_point() +
        coord_cartesian(xlim = xlim)
}

scatter_plot_cart(df, date, value)
```

[image]